# Java 7 glob issue

Tags: java, glob

As much I want, I can't truly understand how to deal with glob in java.
below a short program:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Path p1 = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\all\\Test\\cool.jpg");
        Path p2 = Paths.get("cool.jpg");
        PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**/*.jpg")
        System.out.println(matcher.matches(p1));
        System.out.println(matcher.matches(p2));
    }   
}
```

The result is TRUE / FALSE

Running with "glob: *.jpg" the result is FALSE
/ TRUE

So it looks like first time it search outside of the folder were is located the project (java file) and second time in the folder were is locate the java file.

If I change the second path to any other location (other than my java project is located) the result is: for glob:**/*.jpg -> TRUE/TRUE and for glob: *.jpg -> FALSE/FALSE.

So my question is: I understood well that using glob:*.??? it search in the folder were java project is located and using glob:**/*.??? it search to a specific path other than the folder were java project is located. Because in the documentation is written:

> A glob pattern is specified as a string and is matched against other strings, such as directory or file names. Glob syntax follows several simple rules:
>   An asterisk, *, matches any number of characters (including none).
>   Two asterisks, **, works like * but crosses directory boundaries. This syntax is generally used for matching complete paths.

But nowhere is mentioned that the directory boundaries referring to the directory where Java project is located.

Comment: "If I change the second path to any other location" -> then the path contains a `/`, right? Because that would explain why it then gets matched by the `**/*.jpg` which contains a `/` and doesn't get matched anymore by the `*.jpg` glob which doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Change the glob pattern to this:

```
"glob:**.jpg"
```

Your pattern matches only file paths containing at least one directory.

For example following pattern matches only paths with at least two directories (ex path: a/b/image.jpg)

```
"glob:**/**/*.jpg"
```

And just FYI it does not search the files, it only tests whether given path matches the pattern.

Comment: "And just FYI it does not search the files, it only tests whether given path matches the pattern."  - the sparkle that I needed.

Comment: Looks fine for me now. Thank you all for answers.